# How to make output gif the same length as input gif in ffmpeg

Tags: image, ffmpeg, overlay, gif, frame-rate

Using FFmpeg I need to take a gif and overlay an image on that gif and output it also as a gif. How can I make a command that will make the output gif always be the same length as the original(To have the same number of frames and FPS) and to work no matter what gif is used in input?

This is the command I am using to make the output gif 3 seconds, but I want it to be the same as the input gif, for no matter what gif I use, not fixed at 3 seconds.

```
-y -i gif.gif -i image.jpg -filter_complex [0][1]overlay=100:100:format=auto -t 3 outGif.gif
```

Comment: Does adding `shortest` option to `overlay` filter help? See [the example in documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#gif-1)

Comment: Just remove `-t 3`

Comment: Putting -stream_loop 1 before -i gif and adding :shortest=1 at the end of the filters did the job. Also removing -t 3. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I was doing this on Android and wanted to overlay a couple of stickers on the gif, so when I wanted to make the output a gif with stickers and last as much as the original gif this did the job:

```
   val mediaInformation = FFprobeKit.getMediaInformation(frameFile!!.absolutePath)
    val duration = mediaInformation.mediaInformation.duration
```

Where the frameFile.absoultePath is the Uri to the input gif file.

So I put it like this at the end

```
-t $duration outGif.gif
```

It may help somebody some day if they are doing the same thing, so I wanted to share how I solved it.

P.S.
Using this library: https://github.com/tanersener/ffmpeg-kit